# Getting error class is not defined in Python code

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to programming, I am completing a course on self driving car. This is my code for the assignment (longitudinal vehicle model). I have tried to explain about the code in comment(#). I am getting error:

> class Bicycle is not defined.

Code:

```
from notebook_grader import BicycleSolution, grade_bicycle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

class Bicycle():
    def __init__(self):
    self.xc = 0
    self.yc = 0
    self.theta = 0
    self.delta = 0
    self.beta = 0

    self.L = 2
    self.lr = 1.2
    self.w_max = 1.22

    self.sample_time = 0.01

def reset(self):
    self.xc = 0
    self.yc = 0
    self.theta = 0
    self.delta = 0
    self.beta = 0
class Bicycle(Bicycle):
    def step(self, v, w):
    # ==================================
    #  Implement kinematic model here
    # ==================================
    #so that max rate is not exceeded
    if w > 0:
        w = min(w, self.w_max)
    else:
        w = max(w, -self.w_max)

    #sampling time
    t_sample = 10e-3

    #implementing the differential equations
    xc_dot = v * np.cos(self.theta + self.beta)
    yc_dot = v * np.sin(self.theta + self.beta)
    theta_dot = (v / self.L) * (np.cos(self.beta) * np.tan(self.delta))
    delta_dot = w
    self.beta = np.arctan(self.lr * np.tan(self.delta) / self.L)

    #update equations using the sampling time
    self.xc += xc_dot * t_sample
    self.yc += yc_dot * t_sample
    self.theta += theta_dot * t_sample 
    self.delta += delta_dot * t_sample
```

Comment: `Bicycle` overwrites `Bicycle`. You should use different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined two conflicting classes: both parent and child are "Bicycle". Try to rename them.

Comment: Thanks, but my code starts from implement kinetic model here. All code before that is pre-built and I am not supposed to change the prebuilt code. May you help me please

Comment: Can you please show some more codes? And point out which part is under your control and which part is supposed to be fixed?